# The confusion between fruits & vegetables

Tags: scripture, rituals, ayurveda, vrata, manuscripts

Science classify several eatables, which in layman vernacular are called vegetables, to be fruits and vice-versa. Kind of oxymoron in itself.

[For example:-](https://www.insider.com/fruits-that-are-vegetables-2018-12) Tomato, Cucumber, Chilli, Capsicum, Bell pepper, etc are all popularly taken as vegetables although, are technically fruits.

[And similarly](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/life-style/food-news/vegetables-that-are-fruits-and-fruits-that-are-actually-vegetables-we-finally-have-the-answer/photostory/71348897.cms):- Okra, Grean peas, etc, although popularly held as vegetables are technically fruits.

Generally during a *fast*, we are told by elders and priests that we can consume raw fruits while observing a *vrata* or *upavāsa*, but must not consume vegetables in any form whatsoever.

Thus, my question being, wrt to the technical-scientific classification of fruits and vegetables, how the above situation of what to eat and what not to eat during a *fast*, is resolved as per ayurveda classification and other scriptural injunctions regarding the same?

More importantly, In anyway does this kind of oxymoron classification actually exists in anyform within the Hindu systems?

Comment: We are solid that because fruits can be eaten raw. But vegetables can not be eaten raw.

Comment: 'What to eat' during Fasting or Upavasa is actually or have actually became a scenario of 'believe' or 'dont believe'. Its also regionally varied, seen people eating puffed rice (poha), and even lady finger during Fasting, while I and many others wont agree on it. What about potatoes? Or even sago? We eat sago and potatoes, so why not puffed rice!?

Comment: @Proxy atleast, not eating non veg and onion, garlic, might be a common thread for all, I hope so!

Comment: Fruits and vegetables are, biologically, the same thing. It is only in culinary that they are considered different.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, I don't think so. It depends on the part of the plant to be used. For ex:- Grape's eatable fleshy part is called fruit while the vine part - Grapevine is well used as a vegetable. Both are botanically distinct:- https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/fruits-vs-vegetables